# About the way CGI::Cookie parses cookie

Tags: perl

```
sub parse {
  my ($self,$raw_cookie) = @_;
  my %results;

  my @pairs = split("[;,] ?",$raw_cookie);
  foreach (@pairs) {
    s/\s*(.*?)\s*/$1/;
    my($key,$value) = split("=",$_,2);

    # Some foreign cookies are not in name=value format, so ignore
    # them.
    next if !defined($value);
    my @values = ();
    if ($value ne '') {
      @values = map unescape($_),split(/[&;]/,$value.'&dmy');
      pop @values;
    }
    $key = unescape($key);
    # A bug in Netscape can cause several cookies with same name to
    # appear.  The FIRST one in HTTP_COOKIE is the most recent version.
    $results{$key} ||= $self->new(-name=>$key,-value=>\@values);
  }
  return \%results unless wantarray;
  return %results;
}
```

Anyone knows why `@values = map unescape($_),split(/[&;]/,$value.'&dmy');` is there?

Why must convert it to an array first?

Comment: Netscape? That's a trip down memory lane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted? First? Your question doesn't make much sense. I'm going to assume you want to know what the code that populates `@values` does.

The code in question takes a string containing a series of values, and separates it into a list of values. This list is stored in an array because it's the only type of variable that would hold that.

I'm not clear on why `&dmy` is added and then removed. I suspect it's to prevent empty trailing arguments from being removed by `split`, but a third argument of `-1` would do that more clearly.

Comment: According to the implementation, it seems `CGI::Cookie` can't interpret very complicated cookie,right? Such as `var js_cookie = {a:{b:1}};`,CGI::Cookie` can't interpret `js_cookie`,right?

Comment: @asker, No part of that is a cookie. It can definitely handle a cookie with a value of `{a:{b:1}}`, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: `{a:{b:1}}` is multiple dimensional **hash**,but it seems `CGI::Cookie` only deals with one dimensional **hash**, though under each key,there can be an **array**, but can't hold a **hash** any more.

Comment: @asker, Cookies don't handle hashes at all. Cookies are *strings*, so you'd have to serialise the hash into a string to store it in a cookie. JSON would be an obvious way to serialise your hash.

Comment: But `CGI::Cookie` doesn't has the logic to convert serialized **multiple** dimensional hash back, it seems it can only handle one dimensional hash.

Comment: @asker, It doesn't have logic to parse hashes of one dimension either. The cookies are returned as created.

Comment: It seems we're referring to different things by `cookie` here, for me, the whole stuff is a `cookie`,but seems you're referring to each key as a cookie?

Comment: @asker let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2723/discussion-between-ikegami-and-asker)

Answer (score 1):

A cookie can have multiple fields, and each field can have multiple values. The delimiters used are either semi-colons and ampersands:

```
time=12345678; items=123&456&789; other=abc
```

or alternatively commas and semicolons:

```
time=12345678, items=123;456;789, other=abc
```

Note that in the second case a space may not follow the semi-colon - otherwise it will be interpreted as field assignment delimiter.

So, to answer your question, it converts to an array because a cookie field can have multiple values.

Comment: what if there's `&` in the value?

Comment: @asker, The `&` are *between* the values.

Comment: @ikegami ,so I asked what if there's `&` in the value itself?

Comment: @asker - then you have to escape it - that's why the `map  unescape($_)` is there

Comment: If the cookie author wants the cookie to hold a value which cannot be directly represented (an ampersand, or semicolon) he has to devise an encoding of his own. A string of hex or base64 would seem like a natural choice.

Comment: @asker, Sorry, thought you asked "why ...?". As user5402 answered, you escape it. `&` would be `%26`, `%` would be `%25`.